# Python Selenium: Click element by custom attributes

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to click this button with Selenium:

```
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root jss38 MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary" tabindex="0" type="button" data-test="unifiedCrazyButton"><span class="MuiButton-label">Let's get crazy</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
```

I can't do it by the class name, because there are other buttons with the same class name, and also the xpath value in this format:

```
/html/body/div[10]/div[3]/div/div[3]/button[2]
```

keeps changing which is unfortunate.

The only identifying factor seems to be

```
data-test="unifiedCrazyButton"
```

How can I click this button with Selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-test='unifiedCrazyButton'] span.MuiButton-label"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-test='unifiedCrazyButton']//span[@class='MuiButton-label' and contains(., 'get crazy')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```